# html5 web storage to store user interface preferences

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I need help with some code please guys.  I want to use media storage to store a user interface value for a set user.  I was thinking of offering several styles via style sheets yet cannot work out how i would keep a users preference from the default style sheet, do i need some kind of javascript trigger in the html5 storage?

Comment: ive tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396021/changing-user-preference-stylesheets-via-local-storage

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage to save key/value pairs:

```
localStorage.setItem('alpha','beta');
```

You can later get the value out of the localStorage using:

```
localStorage.alpha;
```

or

```
localStorage.getItem('alpha');
```

You can then use some javascript to change your stylesheet based on the values retreived from the localStorage.

Comment: so calling 'alpha' would display 'beta' for example?

Comment: localStorage.getItem('alpha'); would indeed have the value 'beta'.

Comment: ok thanks, i'll try and work out how to relate the javascript. :)

Comment: so where do i define 'beta'?

Comment: localStorage.setItem('alpha','beta');

Here 'beta' is just a string passed into the setItem method. But you could pass in a variable aswell.

var myString = 'This is a string';
localStorage.setItem('MyKey', myString);

Comment: thanks Robin, most helpful.  I'm going to try and use a hidden value from a button as the variable

Comment: i'm really struggling here on how to set the localstorage and have it work throughout my web app.  i have a page where the user makes a stylsheet preference, and i have javascript that sets the choice as a var in local storage but i don't know what to do next?

Comment: Now you retreive your value(Using the localStorage.getItem()), and load a different stylesheet based on that value. That's how i understood it.