# Changing user preference stylesheets via local storage

Tags: javascript, css, html

**Head of my setting page**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeStyle(title) {
    var lnks = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
    localstorage.css="lnks";
    for (var i = lnks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (lnks[i].getAttribute('rel').indexOf('style') > -1 
          && lnks[i].getAttribute('title')) {
        lnks[i].disabled = true;
        if (lnks[i].getAttribute('title') == title) lnks[i].disabled = false;
      } /* if */
    } /* for */
  } /* function */ 
</script>
```

**Parameters passed to a function on the same page**

```
<button onclick="changeStyle('girly')">Girly</button>
<button onclick="changeStyle('default')">Default</button>
<button onclick="changeStyle('neutral')">Neutral</button>
```

On my index page I'm trying to call a style-sheet chosen via local storage but I can't make it work, could anyone perhaps point out why?

**Index page code (Placed in head)**

```
<script>
  {
  document.onload = localstorage.getitem('css');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't shout. Also, didn't you just ask this question?

Comment: For starters, it doesn't seem you're setting localStorage properly (plus it *needs* to be camelCase)
`localstorage.css="lnks"` should be `localStorage.setItem(key, val)`

Comment: ive amended the code as suggested couzzi - it still doesn't work.  could it be something to do with the javascript implementing the change yet not storing the current change anywhere?